# How to execute sql query files via RPostgreSQL

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I am accessing my PostgreSQL database (9.3) via R using the `RPostgreSQL` package.
I have a few very long and big sql queries (several MB big. generated from raster2pgsql).

**How can I send / execute sql query files as statement within R?**

The normal way

```
\i query.sql
```

does not seem to work via `dbSendQuery`. 
I tried to read in the whole sql file as character vector via `readLines`, however this also fails, because dbSendQuery only supports a single command apparently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dbSendQuery` or `dbGetQuery` is just for the "SQL" part, not the psql commands such as `\i`.
In your case the simplest is indeed to use `readLines` but then wrap `dbGetQuery` in a `sapply` call.

```
con <- dbConnect(...)          #Fill this as usual
queries <- readLines("query.sql")
sapply(queries, function(x) dbGetQuery(con,x))
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Since I use this very often, I have a shortcut for this in my `.Rprofile` file:

```
dbGetQueries<-function(con,queries)sapply(queries,function(x)dbGetQuery(con,x))
```

Of course, you can also go the `system` way:

```
system("psql -U username -d database -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -f query.sql") #Remember to use your actual username, database, host and port
```

Comment: Ahh, a `sapply` was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Found out that occasionally I also needed a `dbClearResult` call. So like this: `sapply(queries,function(x) res <- dbSendQuery(con,x);dbClearResult(res)`

Comment: You will need curly braces in that case though `sapply(queries,function(x){res <- dbSendQuery(con,x);dbClearResult(res)})`

Comment: Or better, use `dbGetQuery()` which automatically does the `dbClearResult()` for you

Comment: Indeed I was assuming that if they were several queries read together from a file they were more likely to be INSERT or UPDATE than SELECT queries, hence the dbSendQuery instead of the dbGetQuery, but you're right dbGetQuery makes in general more sense.