# How to use dynamic values while executing SQL scripts in R

Tags: r, rpostgresql, r-dbi

My R workflow now involves dealing with a lot of queries (`RPostgreSQL` library). I really want to make code easy to maintain and manage in the future.

I started loading large queries from separate `.SQL` files ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160811/how-to-execute-sql-query-files-via-rpostgresql) helped) and it worked great.

Then I started using interpolated values ([that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131569/proper-way-to-pass-parameters-to-query-in-r-dbi/37171135#37171135) helped) which means that I can write

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = ?my_value;
```

and (after loading it into R) interpolate it using `sqlInterpolate(ANSI(), query, value = "stackoverflow")`.

What happens now is I want to use something like this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM ?my_table;
```

but how can I make it work? `sqlInterpolate()` only interpolates safely by default. Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlInterpolate()` is for substituting values only, not other components like table names. You could use other templating frameworks such as [brew](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brew/index.html) or [whisker](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/whisker/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

In `?DBI::SQL`, you can read:

> By default, any user supplied input to a query should be escaped using
>   either `dbQuoteIdentifier()` or `dbQuoteString()` depending on whether it
>   refers to a table or variable name, or is a literal string.

Also, on [this page](https://db.rstudio.com/run-queries-safely/#manual-escaping):

> You may also need `dbQuoteIdentifier()` if you are creating tables or
>   relying on user input to choose which column to filter on.

So you can use:

```
sqlInterpolate(ANSI(), 
               "SELECT count(*) FROM ?my_table", 
               my_table = dbQuoteIdentifier(ANSI(), "table_name"))
# <SQL> SELECT count(*) FROM "table_name"
```